# WiFi adapter settings

Tags: python, batch

Yesterday I have found that I can't use the wireless network at some spots in my house. I used another modem as a WiFi booster and I managed to cover these spots.

The problem is that when I go to these dead spots I need to use static IP and change my primary DNS servers, or I get limited connection. Also, I still want to use DHCP when I'm not in these spots.

I have written two Batch files and a Python script to define the wireless adapter settings. I would like someone to take a look and suggest how to improve it.

**Batch Files** (I'm using shortcuts because of the option to run them as administrator)

1. **DeadSpots.bat.ink**

   ```
   netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static 192.168.x.x 255.255.255.0 192.168.x.x
   netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 192.168.x.x primary # This is the second modem
   netsh interface ip add dns "Wi-Fi" ISP.dns.IP index=2
   ```
2. **Regular.bat.ink**

   ```
   netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" dhcp
   netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" source=dhcp
   ```

**Python code**

```
import subprocess as sub

def WiFi():
    filepath1 = Path_To_DeadSpots.bat.ink
    filepath2 = Path_To_Regular.bat.ink
    loc = input("Please choose your location: 1-Rooms, 2-Rest \n")
    while(loc != "1" and loc != "2"):
        print("Wrong input, please choose again")
        loc = input("Please choose your location: 1-Rooms, 2-Rest \n")
    if loc == "1":
        p = sub.Popen(filepath1,shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE)
    else:
        p = sub.Popen(filepath2,shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE)
WiFi()
```

Comment: Are you using [WDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system)?

Comment: @200_success, No, should I?

Comment: That seems like the proper way to extend your WiFi range, making one seamless network at Layer 2, without weird workarounds like this.

Comment: @200_success, I tried using WDS. Unfortuneately, didnt get the required result...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward, so I don't have a ton of critiques.

#### Naming

PEP8 conventions say your function should probably be named `wifi` (which is not a great name)

The names `filepath1` and `filepath2` aren't very helpful.

#### Input

You're repeating yourself unnecessarily while getting user input.  Furthermore, try to keep your functions pure and handle user input separately.

#### Magic numbers

It might be cleaner to make `"1"` and `"2"` constants.  Even cleaner is to use a dictionary, like I did.

#### Unused variables

You never use `p`, so I don't see a reason to assign to it.

Here is my full rewrite of your Python program.  I don't know enough about the batch scripting to comment there.

```
import subprocess as sub


room_to_batchfile = {
    "1": "Path/To/DeadSpots.bat.ink",
    "2": "Path/To/Regular.bat.ink"
}


def setup_wifi(room):
    sub.Popen(room_to_batchfile[room], shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loc = ""
    while loc not in room_to_batchfile:
        loc = input("Please choose your location: 1-Rooms, 2-Rest \n")

    setup_wifi(loc)
```

Honestly, given the small nature of this it might not even make sense to make it a function.  If you plan on expanding this then it might be worthwhile to implement these changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to, you could do this entirely in batch, and in only 1 batch file very easily. Using your existing code I threw this together for you.

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 0F

:Start
TITLE SET IP
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO 1) Set DHCP IP
ECHO 2) Set static IP
ECHO.
SET /P Area=Make your selection [1,2]... 
IF %Area%==1 GOTO :Regular
IF %Area%==2 GOTO :DeadSpot
CLS
TITLE INVALID SELECTION
COLOR FC
ECHO "%Area%" isn't a valid selection choice, please try a valid selection.
ECHO We'll return to the previous menu.
PAUSE
GOTO :Start

:Regular
netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" dhcp
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" source=dhcp
GOTO :EOF

:DeadSpot
netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static 192.168.x.x 255.255.255.0 192.168.x.x
netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 192.168.x.x primary    :: This is the second modem
netsh interface ip add dns "Wi-Fi" ISP.dns.IP index=2
GOTO:EOF
```

Than if you wanted to run the batch file as an Administrator, just add this to your batch file, it should work I grabbed it from another thread here on SO

```
:: BatchGotAdmin (Put after @ECHO OFF, towards the top)
REM --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
```